# Could you please rephrase or simplify it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

Macfarlane notes that even though 17th-century Japan had large cities, high literacy rates, even a futures market, it had turned its back on the essence of any work-based revolution by giving up labor-saving devices such as animals, afraid that they would put people out of work.

Comment: If you try out your understanding of the sentence, and we can help you with some improvements, we will. It starts with you. Click the '?' icon for Help/Tour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Macfarlane notes that even though 17th-century Japan had **(i)** large cities, **(ii)** high literacy rates, **[and] (iii)** even a futures market, it **(= Japan)** had **[nevertheless]** {turned its back on the essence **(= the essential constituent)** of any work-based revolution **(=industrial revolution)**} by giving up labor-saving devices **-for example** animals, [**because they (= the Japanese) were]** afraid that they would put people out of work.